# How do we know what the dipole moment of "The Earth Magnet" is?

Tags: dipole-moment, geomagnetism

It is given in my textbook and one other book(that I got from the library) that:-

> ...The earth has a magnetic dipole of dipole moment about $8.0\times 10^{22} \mathbf{ J.T^{-1}}$

The book doesn't state how we know it and it uses the word 'assume' which confuses me a little bit. Internet doesn't seem to help. Sources are welcomed.

Comment: We have mapped the magnetic field, both at the Earth's surface as well as in orbit.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetometer for various devices that can be used to map magnetic fields.

Comment: Got it but the textbook uses the word "assume" as if it is an assumed value. Is this just a wrong word which wasn't meant to be there?

Comment: The Earth's magnetic field (and thus the magnetic dipole moment) is a measured quantity. We don't assume it's value. Furthermore, the quote you provide does not include the word "assume" so it's not clear from your question exactly what is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it's a sort of least squares fit to measurements at the surface. But first, let's suppose that the source of Earth's field is a dipole that is at the Earth's center and pointing towards the geographic North Pole. Given that, it only takes one measurement at the surface to determine what the dipole moment $m$ is. Let's say $R$ is the distance to the center in meters, $B$ is the magnitude of the surface field in teslas, and $\lambda$ is the latitude. Then the dipole moment is given by (see [Dipole Moment Variation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjx9Yj35OHqAhXWGTQIHWlPC6I4ChAWMAF6BAgDEAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Figpphome.ucsd.edu%2F%7Ecathy%2FPublications%2FPreprints%2Fdipole.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2t7jfGYM9afJeXZSpSM2uT)):
$$m = \frac{4 \pi R^3}{\mu_0} \frac{B}{\sqrt{1 + 3\sin^2\lambda}}.$$

In reality, Earth's magnetic field has a much more complex source and it is only partly dipolar. To find out what that dipolar part is, we need a model for the magnetic field at the surface. This involves fitting large numbers of surface measurements to [spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics), analogous to a polynomial fit but for the surface of a sphere. The three lowest-degree terms give a vector for Earth's dipole moment. It turns out that the best-fitting dipole moment is at an angle of about $11^\circ$ off the rotational axis (see [the Wikipedia article on Earth's magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field#Dipolar_approximation)).

I know this is rather technical, and I'm sorry for that. I couldn't find a source that explained it in any simpler terms.

Comment: Thank you so much!